# Nignx Upstream Timeout Strange Upstream Url

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

we are faceing with strange problem. When our nginx has more then 300 user connection (we can see this from google analytics), it begins to give below error in logs:

[warn] 8#8: *231723 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.10.171, server: [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com), request: "POST /api/quote HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://xx.xx.xx.xx.:443/v1/quote", host: "www.domain.com"

[error] 8#8: *230844 connect() failed (110: Operation timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.32.23.28, server: [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com), request: "POST /api/quote HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://xx.xx.xx.xx:443/v1/quote", host: "www.domain.com"

The strange things is this in upstream part should be hostname, but we see IP of hostname. In parallel when we check via postman backend urls, we don't get any errors.
Our config is below :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k; 
    client_body_timeout 90; 
    client_header_timeout 90;
    keepalive_timeout  90;
    keepalive_requests 100;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    send_timeout 90; 
    sendfile on; 
    tcp_nopush on; 
    tcp_nodelay on;
    server_tokens off;

    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;

    proxy_intercept_errors  on;
    #proxy_set_header        HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For 
 $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    
    location ~ ^/(sitemap.xml) {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ ^/(robots.txt) {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /instant/ {
        proxy_pass  ${VUE_APP_API_INSTANT_URL};
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        #proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_buffer_size 16k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 24k;
        proxy_buffers 64 4k;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        #pagespeed off;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass  ${VUE_APP_API_ORDER_URL};
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        #proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_buffer_size 16k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 24k;
        proxy_buffers 64 4k;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        #pagespeed off;
    }

    error_page  404              /index.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # Leverage browser caching
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|svg|map|webp|ttf|woff)$ {
        access_log                            off;
        log_not_found                         off;
        gzip_static                            on;
        gzip_comp_level                         2;
        add_header          Cache-Control private;
        expires                               30d;
    }

    location ~ /\. { #Hide . files
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off; 
        deny all;
    }

    open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
}
```